# Is there any way I can watch the building process of gtk+ 2 widgets? (C in Windows)

Tags: c, gtk2

I am building a gtk+ (v2) using C and Code::Blocks in Win7.

As I proceed, I find placing widgets in tables (using gtk_table_attach) and keeping track of left_attach, right_attach, top_attach and bottom_attach confusing sometimes. (in some cases I am using complex calculations for creating a grid like column * 6 + offset + 1.

It would be nice to observe the placement of these widgets when the gtk_table_attach is called rather then all at once at the end in the gtk_widget_show_all statement.

Can this be done?

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: You said you're using GTK+2, but this page might have some useful info: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-running.html

Comment: That is a fantastic link, thank you. I will experiment with this. I particularly like the interactive option.